# More efficient/preferred way of using Session variables?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session-variables

I have an ASP DataGrid and I'm applying sorting to it.  Well, as I was looking at an example, they had a function similar in function, different in name, to:

```
Private Sub dgTasks_SortGrid(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridSortCommandEventArgs) Handles dgTasks.SortCommand
    Dim strSortDirection As String = Session("SortDir")
    If strSortDirection = Nothing Then
        strSortDirection = " ASC "
    Else
        If strSortDirection = " ASC " Then
            strSortDirection = " DESC "
        Else
            strSortDirection = " ASC "
        End If
    End If
    Session("SortDir") = strSortDirection
    BindData(e.SortExpression & strSortDirection)
End Sub
```

Well, me trying to make shortcuts and make things "easier" thought maybe this would be best:

```
Private Sub dgTasks_SortGrid(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridSortCommandEventArgs) Handles dgTasks.SortCommand
    If Session("SortDir") = Nothing Then
        Session("SortDir") = " ASC "
    Else
        If Session("SortDir") = " ASC " Then
            Session("SortDir") = " DESC "
        Else
            Session("SortDir") = " ASC "
        End If
    End If
    BindData(e.SortExpression & Session("SortDir"))
End Sub
```

However, as I was thinking about it, I figured maybe `Session("SortDir")` has to make a request everytime and it could have some affect or drawbacks.  But I wasn't sure.  Does anyone have any links that would explain the best or preferred method.  Thanks.

Comment: Isn't the outer `If` condition redundant?

Comment: Yes it was.  I was typing it as I was thinking it.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking up the Session value twice (one read and one write) rather than four times seems clearly better. The performance difference won’t be noticable by the user, but all those redundant lookups would make most programmers very uncomfortable! And there are some occasions where this kind of thing could make a noticable difference, depeding on the amount of data stored in the collection, and the type of lookup performed (hash table, binary search, sequential search, etc.), so it’s probably not a good habit to get into.

Comment: Yeah, it made me uneasy, that's why I asked.  Since I'm technically new to web programming, I thought maybe the uneasiness was unawareness.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good use of Session in this scenario simply because there are better ways to do it. Sessions should contain specific data about the end user in some way.

Try something along these lines

```
Private Property _SortDir As Nullable(Of String) ''# I used "Nullable(Of" because I don't know if you are able to use "String?"
Public Property SortDir() As Nullable(Of String)
    Get
        Return _SortDir
    End Get
    Set
        _SortDir = value
    End Set
End Property

Private Sub dgTasks_SortGrid(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridSortCommandEventArgs) Handles dgTasks.SortCommand

    If SortDir.IsNullOrEmpty Or SortDir = "DESC" Then
        SortDir = "ASC"
    Else
        SortDir = "DESC"
    End If

    BindData(e.SortExpression & SortDir))
End Sub
```

I did think of one other reason you might want to retain the sortOrder in a session, however it would have some nasty side affects.  If you want to leave the current page and come back later with the same sort order, then leave it in a Session... BUT, what if you have another grid elsewhere on the site, are you going to have a different session variable for it? or are you going to retain your existing sort order on the new grid?  These are all things you need to think about when using Session variables.

If you're staying on the existing page, then use the items that are at your disposal for that page. Heck, you "could" use the `_VIEWSTATE` to store the sort order as well (though I wouldn't recommend it).

Remember, the web is designed to be stateless, so manufacturing a "state" is a little undesirable.

Lastly.

Another option for you would be to put the sort order in your querystring and forget about everything else (doesn't totally work with AJAX).

Comment: The problem with that is that SortDir gets reset everytime.  Thanks though.

Comment: You're altering your Session Variable every time anyways. Sessions drop a cookie on the client machine, so not only are you resetting the variable every time, but with a session, you're also sending data over the wire every time.

Comment: Well, I should have mentioned this in the OP but this is a small internal site with two pages that is not expected to grow.  This will be the only grid in the site.  The issue I had was when I would sort the column, the asp:DataGrid would reload the page and it would reset all varaibles, and the only way I could think to do it was using a session variable.  If I didn't, then it would sort the table once, but if I tried it again, it's sort it the same way, everytime.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want session-level persistence, I'd add two small changes to **rockinthesixstring**'s suggestion:

**(Warning: C# coder trying to write VB!)**

```
Private Property _SortDir As Nullable(Of String)
Public Property SortDir() As Nullable(Of String)
    Get
        Return _SortDir
    End Get
    Set
        Session("SortDir") = value
        _SortDir = value
    End Set
End Property

Private Sub dgTasks_SortGrid(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridSortCommandEventArgs) Handles dgTasks.SortCommand

    If SortDir = "ASC" Then    'I think the outer If block was redundant''
        SortDir = "DESC"
    Else
        SortDir = "ASC"
    End If

    BindData(e.SortExpression & SortDir))
End Sub

Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        _SortDir = Session("SortDir")
    End If
End Sub
```

This code is mostly C&P'd from **rockinthesixstring**, so if you use this answer, please either accept or upvote his.

Comment: Also, if you're ensuring that the property has a value in the Page_Load, then there's no reason to have it `Nullable` - Yes, there are many ways to skin this cat ;-)

Comment: @rockinthesixstring, aren't strings already nullable in VB? They are in C#, and actually every other language I know of, come to think of it. Is that just to initialize it to null?